# Textbox scrolling is too slow with a reasonably big text in it - anything to be done about it?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

When I load around 100KB text in TextBox it begins to work really laggy.
Like scrolling it, etc. It just feels bad.

Is there any reasonably easy workaround around it?

I'd like to be able to load something up to a megabyte of text without huge lag in scrolling.

On top of scrolling there are problems with selecting text or editing it, it becomes very slow and uncomfortable too.

Comment: See this article about deferred scrolling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.isdeferredscrollingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx. You may need to modify the default text box template to set the property on the template scrollviewer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBox` doesn't have virtualization, and so isn't really designed to support large amounts of text. You will need to use a different kind of control, and possibly think about whether your expanse of text really needs to be just a single string: could it be broken down into smaller objects that make sense?

`RichTextBox`, `ListBox` or `DataGrid` are all good candidates for the kind of control you should be using - depending on what you want to do and how much you can break up the text into parts.

Comment: The `ListBox` and `DataGrid` will have the concept of `SelectedItem`, and I don't think this will be helpful. An `ItemsControl` using a virtualizing panel should do the job.

Comment: Have you tried them, with just one item? I'm not too sure how deep their virtualization goes - whether it extends to a single item or only over multiple item. Easy to test though.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding: The virtualization will only have an effect if the text **is** broken into smaller blocks and there is an item for each block. I'm not suggesting using only one single item inside an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: dammit, bounty is lost sorry. I dont get it, why I cant be afk for a day and still be able to grant bounty

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try a quick and cheap solution with an `ItemsControl`, assuming - as others did before me - that your text is separated into smaller blocks.

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Paragraphs}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You may need to strip down the `TextBox` template (MouseOver state, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Control with virtualization, perhaps a DataGrid since you need the data to be editable.

It would also be better to split your data into smaller chunks.